# Solidity - The Constructor should be Payable if you send value during transfer

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens

I was just wondering and do some search on how token works, and what I get is :

Send ethereum to smart contract => Smart contract have a price for the token, the value, and return back the token to `msg.sender` as address by dividing amount of value sent and the token price, so I created following contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleToken {
    address client;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    uint remaining;
    uint price;

uint ethval;

mapping (address => uint) investors;
event testDebug(string _msg,address client,uint256 totalSupply,uint receivedValue);
function SimpleToken(uint _totalSupply) //constructor
{
    client = msg.sender;
    totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    remaining = 0;
}

function setEthValue(uint _value){
    ethval = _value;
}

function sendToken() payable 
{
    testDebug("Before",client,totalSupply,investors[msg.sender]);
    assert(remaining < totalSupply);
    uint noOfTokens = ethval/price;
    assert(noOfTokens < totalSupply-remaining); 
    investors[msg.sender] = noOfTokens;
    remaining = remaining+noOfTokens;

    testDebug("After",client,remaining,noOfTokens);

    client.transfer(noOfTokens);

}

function setTokenPrice(uint _price)
{ 
    price = _price;
}

function getEthVal() constant returns(uint){
    return ethval;
}
}
```

Then I set the input value as follows :

[image]

When I run `sendToken` function which will be sending token to sender account, why does it return error

> The Constructor should be Payable if you send value during
>   transfer

I tried adding `payable` to the constructor but it gave me no luck either.

What is wrong with my simple contract ?

Answer (score 1):

A few possibilities:

1. `price` could be 0, resulting in a divide-by-zero.
2. `price` could be such that `noOfTokens` is greater than the remaining tokens.
3. If neither of those are stopping things first, `client.transfer(noOfTokens)` probably is.

`client.transfer(noOfTokens)` tries to transfer ether to `client`. The amount of ether attempted in the transfer is `noOfTokens` wei. I see no reason to expect the contract to have that much ether.

You probably want this (`msg.value` instead of `ethval`) and transferring that much to `client`:

```
function sendToken() payable 
{
    testDebug("Before",client,totalSupply,investors[msg.sender]);
    assert(remaining < totalSupply);
    uint noOfTokens = msg.value / price;
    assert(noOfTokens < totalSupply-remaining); 
    investors[msg.sender] = noOfTokens;
    remaining = remaining+noOfTokens;

    testDebug("After",client,remaining,noOfTokens);

    client.transfer(msg.value);    
}
```

Just be sure to actually transfer ether when you call `sendToken()`. (You can set the amount of ether sent with the transaction in the upper right in Remix with the "value" field.)

Comment: Firstly, I already took a screenshot when its value is not zero (I already made sure of it), when noOfToken is zero, the transaction will be succeed. At the debug mode, it reverts the whole transaction at line of client.transfer(noOfToken). And if you see above, I put large amount of supplied token. I already made sure all of your points. But unfortunately no luck :(

Comment: `client.transfer(noOfToken)` doesn't transfer tokens. It transfers ether.

Comment: In your screenshot you're not sending any ether. (The "Value" field is 0.) And your code is trying to transfer the amount of ether equal to `noOfToken`, which doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you can explain exactly what you want this function to do. (`remaining` is also quite confusing... it seems to really mean the opposite, since it starts at 0 and goes up.)

Comment: (Or just try my code, but be sure to actually send ether.)